# Data from neo4j is not loading properly in yEd

Tags: graph, neo4j, graph-databases, neo4j-apoc

I have exported the data from neo4j database into graphml file and loaded it into yEd live. The data got loaded but I am not getting the names on the nodes.

Below is the code used to export the data.

```
call apoc.export.graphml.query("MATCH (n) OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-(m) RETURN 
n,r,m LIMIT 20 ","data5.graphml",{})
```

below is the entry in the graphml file for node.

```
<node id="n0" labels=":Entity"><data key="labels">:Entity</data><data 
key="name">XXXX</data></node>
```

This is the data how it looks like in neo4j visualization.

[image: neo4j visualization with node names]

Below is how it is in the yEd live.
[image: yEd visualization not showing the node names]

How can I get the names on nodes in yEd as well like I am getting in the neo4j default visualization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A most basic GraphML for yEd Live with a node and a node label looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<graphml xsi:schemaLocation="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns http://www.yworks.com/xml/schema/graphml.html/2.0/ygraphml.xsd " 
  xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns" 
  xmlns:y="http://www.yworks.com/xml/yfiles-common/3.0" 
  xmlns:x="http://www.yworks.com/xml/yfiles-common/markup/3.0" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <key id="labels" for="node" attr.name="NodeLabels" y:attr.uri="http://www.yworks.com/xml/yfiles-common/2.0/NodeLabels"/>
  <graph>
    <node id="n0">
      <data key="labels">
        <x:List>
          <y:Label>
            <y:Label.Text>My Label</y:Label.Text>
          </y:Label>
        </x:List>
      </data>
    </node>
  </graph>
</graphml>
```

I can also recommend to use our free online tool [Neo4j Explorer](https://www.yworks.com/neo4j-explorer/). You can use it to query a Neo4j database and visualize the results. Neo4j Explorer can also export GraphMLs that you can open and edit in yEd Live.